# Windows 8.1 Bluetooth searching issue

Tags: bluetooth, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, windows-shell

I have a windows 8.1 based lap top which supports Bluetooth.

I wrote a java based bluetooth server which gets connections from Android.

The issue is, the device sometimes get invisible(or to say not shown) on android devices.

I've tried with other laptops or Android phones, but sometimes it just doesn't get searched.

I think it's not about my java server program. Even if there's a problem with my program, it should at least be shown on the bluetooth search list of other devices.

I found a very crude solution about this issue. 
Always running the 'change pc settings(not the exact name)' app of windows 8.1, and going to 'PC, devices' -> Bluetooth makes it always searchable. If I turn this off(I mean the 'change pc settings' app, not turning off bluetooth), the bluetooth cannot be found by other devices.

Why is this happening? My purpose is, bluetooth server must be turned on automatically after boot, but the reliability of the bluetooth device is failing my intention. However, since my crude solution above is temporarily solving my issue, I do not think it's a hardware issue.

So, my question is :
1) Why is this happening? And how can I mend this?
2) How can I run windows metro app through windows shell? If I can't find any other solution about this, I will have to write a batch script to always run the solution thing above.

Answer (score 0):

Going to Change PC Settings>PC and devices>Bluetooth is initiating a Bluetooth device search. As a side effect, the Bluetooth is also made Discoverable (pairing mode). However, this Discoverable setting is temporary, only while the PC is searching for remote Bluetooth devices.

If you wish to keep Bluetooth Discoverable at all times, you need to check the "Allow Bluetooth devices to find this PC" button box, found in Bluetooth Settings. I found Bluetooth settings by right clicking the Bluetooth system icon. Can also be found in Devices and Printers, by right clicking the Bluetooth adapter icon.